# installing unreal devkit 4 for mac: image not recognized

Tags: macos, unreal-development-kit

I downloaded Unreal Development Kit 4,
I see a warning
" image not recognized "
while opening .dmg file.
any idea?
I can't find any information from anywhere.

I'm currently using osX 10.9.2 macbook pro,
meeting every requirements they officially require.

any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. The PROBLEM was that it didnt completely download the file.

The SOLUTION is to keep downloading the files again and again with a proper internet connection and you should get around 45MB File.

Cheers !